# What happens to Edgar Deems' body in "Tremors"?

Tags: plot-explanation, tremors

In *Tremors* (1990) we see Val and Earl taking town drunk Edgar Deems' body to the Doctor, who identifies de-hydration as the cause of his death.

The next we see Val and Earl they are on their way out of Perfection with no body in the back of their truck.

I assume the doctor doesn't have it as he and his wife are living in a caravan. Is it possible it is in one of Walter's freezers?

Comment: Surely the logical answer is "buried or cremated"?

Comment: @F1Krazy where, when, by who? I have seen some behind the scenes and DVD extra stuff but nothing that covers Edgar's body

Comment: I don't know, I haven't seen the film. I'm guessing the specifics were omitted because it's really not important in the grand scheme of things, but as I said, burial or cremation *seems* like the logical answer.

Comment: It's not shown or discussed but since the doctor evaluated him, I'd assume the doctor took him away to Bigsby (next town over). The doctor did have a station wagon and the roads were open at that point.

Comment: @DustinDavis but the next we see the doctor his wife tells him they gave to go to Bigsby the next day so don't they took the body there?

Comment: @Seamusthedog From what I recall the next we see them, it's night time and they're at their house working on it and the discussion was that the cinder blocks came in so they have to go back to bigsby.

Comment: @DustinDavis apologies for my poor wording last comment. Yes the next we see the doc and his wife it's the night but the implied it's the same day. Why go to Bigsby to drop off the body, return to Perfection then go back to Bigsby the next day? I know the answer is not in the film as such but there is usually someone with canopy of the original script etc that has the answer.

Comment: @Seamusthedog my point was that they didn't know they had to pick up in bigsby. The doctor was surprised when his wife told him. Or, the doctor had simply forgotten the delivery would be on XYZ date. But if the doctor did in fact take edgar, it's because it would be his obligation. Perfection was a town of only a few people, no services to support a death. If it wasn't the doctor, it would have to of been the police but we don't see anyone else and it's never mentioned. I'll have to re-watch (it's my fav movie anyway), but hopefully someone has a script.

Comment: @dustindavis watched it again last night (twice in 2 days) and the doctors wife says 'we have to go to Bigsby tomorrow' implying they haven't just been there, given this was 1990 no-one had a mobile phone and they were living in a caravan I doubt they had a phone there. Could Edgar's body be in the chest freezer Val unplugs in Walters store before Walter gets killed? Will dig out the DVD but sure there isn't anything there explaining it.

Answer (score 3):

This is addressed in a little more detail in the [film script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Tremors.html).

Val and Earl drop the body off with the Doctor (Jim) and his wife, Megan. She states that they'll **telephone the coroner in Bixby and arrange for the body to be collected** once he's finished examining the body.

> Jim examines Edgar's body in the bed of Val and Earl's pick-up truck.  Val, Earl and Megan talk in subdued tones.
>
> **VAL:** *Real sorry to bother you, Megan, but we figured since Jim's a doctor...*
>
> **MEGAN:** *No, it's fine.  You did the right thing.  When Jim is done we'll call the Coroner's office in Bixby. We'll take care of it. (shakes her head) Poor Edgar.*

At this point in the film the road out of Perfection is still passable, the phones are still working and Bixby is only 30 miles away. There's no reason for her to have delayed the phone call, so presumably Edgar's body was safely in the Coroner's Office within an hour or two of Val and Earl dropping him off at Doctor Jim's house.

Comment: They cut this riveting exchange in return for more screentime with the graboids. Did they make the right editorial decision? Only time will tell...